# Comparing values in two dictionaries when keys are different

Tags: python, dictionary, compare, key-value

I need to compare values between two dictionaries with DIFFERENT keys, and put the results in the third dictionary. Input:

```
a={1:[0,0], 2:[1,0], 3:[1,2]}
b={4:[1,2], 5:[1,3]}
```

Output: I want to have two out dictionaries, both of them will have keys copied from 'b'. In all cases I would like to ignore entries '0'. The first output shows how many keys in 'a' had the exact same value as key in b.

```
c={4:3, 5:0}
```

The second output dict shows how many keys in 'a' had 1 (and only 1) value the same as key in b.

```
d={4:[2], 5:[2,3]}
```

I tried doing this like that:

```
c=dict.fromkeys(b.keys())
d=dict.fromkeys(b.keys())

for k, v in b.iteritems():
    TST_s, TST_d= v[0], v[1]
    for each, every in a.iteritems():
        TRN_s, TRN_d= every[0], every[1]
        if TST_s == TRN_s and TST_d==TRN_d:
            c[k].append(each)
        elif TST_s == TRN_s and TST_d!=TRN_d:
            d[k].append(each)
        elif TST_s!= TRN_s and TST_d==TRN_d:
            d[k].append(each)
        else:
            pass
```

But I'm getting

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS. I know that the code could be simplified, but I am not very talented when it comes to programing, plus I haven't accounted for '0' yet which I want to remove at a later stage. At the moment I just want to get it to produce output...

Comment: What is the question? The error seems pretty clear

Comment: @wumm why the rollback?

Comment: @TimCastelijns You shouldn't change the original code, specially not correct any errors. It's better to leave a comment, so that the author learns what's wrong about. http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: In your post `b=[4:[1,2], 5:[1,3]]` for example, both `a` and `b` is a list of dicts not a dict. Please correct your question

Comment: @wumm ah of course you're right, I confused myself

Comment: Doh! Stupid mistake. It's not like this in my original code, so this is not the cause of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c[k] and d[k] is None because `dict.fromkeys(b.keys())` returns `{4:None, 5:None}`